# How to create linked tables from MDB to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, linked-tables

I have an app which is having problems with data-access to an MDB database over a wireless network.

Would a quick solution be to have a local MDB file on all workstations that links all its tables to a SQL Server database?

Would this be a way to avoid having to re-write all data-access code in the app?

Comment: Can you describe the problem you are having? Maybe post an example of your data access code? How many workstations are we talking about? Are there other reasons to move to SQL Server?

Comment: Access' network performance has never been great, and over WIFI could be a never ending source of headache's, I think you are always best to give each user a local copy.

Comment: @Matt : If each user has a local copy then how will they be able to share the database?

Comment: @CraigJ All local copies will have links to the same SQL-Server, or are you storing data in Access as well?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that will do pretty well. We have many customers connected in this way.
However it's not an easy task. Not sure if all the effort required will pay for itself.
And you have some new maintenance and deploying problems.

The steps to follow are this:

**1)** Migrate your tables to SQLServer
**2)** Create an ODBC Data Source that will be used to connect to your backend database
**3)** Connect your tables
**4)** Rename your connected tables to remove the schema qualifier (eg. "dbo_") so your linked tables have the same name as before.

Now it's time to test all your code.
Hopefully you will not have to rewrite anything.

The real problems lies on client PCs where you need to create an ODBC data source that match your original one. Also if you redistribute your front-end database it's possibile you have to reconnect all the tables from the client PCs. 
You need to call a function like this:

```
Public Function UpdateODBCTables() As Boolean

    On Error GoTo Exit_On_Error
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
    Dim sDSN As String
    Dim sDB As String
    Dim sComputer As String
    Dim sDesc As String
    Dim sApp As String
    Dim strConnect As String

    sDSN = "YOUR_DSN_NAME"
    sDB = "YOUR_DATABASE_NAME"
    sComputer = "YOUR_COMPUTER_NAME"
    sApp = "YOUR_APP_NAME"
    sDesc = "DESCRIPTION_OF_YOUR_APP"

    strConnect = "ODBC;DSN=" & sDSN & ";" & _
                 "DATABASE=" & sDB & ";" & _
                 "WSID=" & sComputer & ";" & _
                 "TrustedConnection=Yes;" & _
                 "Description=" & sDesc & ";" & _
                 "APP=" & sApp ";"
    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    ' Loop over tabledefs of ODBC type and reconnect
    For Each tdf In dbs.TableDefs
        If tdf.Connect <> "" And Left(tdf.Connect, 4) = "ODBC" And Left(tdf.Name, 1) <> "~" Then
            tdf.Connect = strConnect
            tdf.RefreshLink
        End If
    Next
    dbs.TableDefs.Refresh
    UpdateODBCTables = True

Exit_On_Return:
   Set dbs = Nothing
   Exit Function

Exit_On_Error:
   MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "YOUR_MESSAGE_TITLE"
   Resume Exit_On_Return
End Function
```

Comment: How have you dealt with the issue of queries pulling the whole table over to the client? On larger databases, wouldn't this be a killer to performance?

Comment: Access does not pull the whole table over the network even when using a file share with the data file sitting on a network shared folder. So in the 18+ year history the Access data engine NEVER did pull the whole table over the network as long as an index is available for use. So pulling one customer record out of 1 million rows means only one record comes down the network pipe and this ALSO true if the backend data file is replaced with SQL server. The whole table idea is an urban myth perpetrated by those with little knowledge as to how the JET (now called ACE) data engine functions.

Comment: The problem is the 'queries pulling the whole table over to the client'. If so, as @kallal says, a switch to SQLServer is meaningless. This is the situation in which you, definitively, should rewrite your code.